# Magento 2 Rounding Tax Calculation Issue

Tags: magento2, tax, vat, tax-calculation

I use Magento 2.3.5p1 with catalog prices without tax. I have issue with tax rounding on storefront.
Example calculation.

I get following result on Magento storefront for 21% vat;

```
45.45 * 1.21 = 54.99
```

But it must be **€55.00** (imported order from feedmanager). I don't know where i make a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Magento [official document](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/tax/quick-reference.html#tax-calculation-methods) can help you determining and playing around tax settings.

And this [warning message](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/tax/warning-messages.html) section covers scenarios, when rounding warning can occur.

If you must debug, you could put a breakpoint [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/455ca54f5479cedf00d4d10b8a6289a72eaab784/app/code/Magento/Tax/Model/Calculation/AbstractCalculator.php#L406) to check what's really going on and review the flow of calculation.

Comment: it didn't help me solve the problem